# SQL Server - How make allow NULL value in column

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

I'm newbie level in SQL Server

I want to allow null value in column, but it can't save.

[image: enter link description here]

So I will re-create a new table with same structure.

Please your help to allow null value in column with SQL script.
Thank you..

Comment: there is no attached picture (and I don't think you'll be able to attach, your rep is too low), so your question makes no sense. Please explain yourself

Comment: @Amit - the image was in the question markdown http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30548532/edit/bbbba9cc-27cf-4c55-96fd-87106f29146a

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks as though the designer is trying to re-create the whole table and warning you about that.

It is possible to allow it to do so by disabling the option specified in the error message to "prevent saving changes that require the table to be recreated" but there is no need for this here.

You can just run

```
ALTER TABLE SAMPLE_UPL
  ALTER COLUMN KORESKI VARCHAR(300) NULL
```

Or simply

```
ALTER TABLE SAMPLE_UPL
  ALTER COLUMN KORESKI VARCHAR(300)
```

(as altering an existing column always sets it to allow NULL unless explicitly specified otherwise)

Comment: i think this one is better answer as it describes the root cause of the OP's problem and provides simplest solution. [+1]

Answer (score 3):

go in table design and checked check box this can allow you null values[image]

script of this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AWBuildVersion](
    [SystemInformationID] [tinyint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Database Version] [nvarchar](25) NULL,
    [VersionDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_AWBuildVersion_SystemInformationID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [SystemInformationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```